# Problem when trying to update the Azure API Gateway operation backend via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, azure-api-management

All i want is to deploy my Azure API gateway with api operations which are defined in the open API yaml document. My below code deploys the windows function app and the API gateway and also i can see that my required operations are listed with in the API.

Issue is when i am importing the open API document, then i am not able to update the individual API operation backend which should be my Azure function app URL.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "windows-function-rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = "west europe"

  tags = {
    "Environment"              = "Dev"
    "CostResponsible"          = "IT"
    "projectName"              = "crm-cost-estimate"
    "aks-managed-cluster-name" = "unknown"
  }
}



resource "azurerm_storage_account" "windows-storage-account" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  tags = {
    "Environment"              = "Dev"
    "CostResponsible"          = "IT"
    "projectName"              = "crm-cost-estimate"
    "aks-managed-cluster-name" = "unknown"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "windows-service-plan" {
  name                = var.service_plan_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
  tags = {
    "Environment"              = "Dev"
    "CostResponsible"          = "IT"
    "projectName"              = "crm-cost-estimate"
    "aks-managed-cluster-name" = "unknown"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "windows-application-insights" {
  name                = "application-insights-${var.azurerm_windows_function_app}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  application_type    = "Node.JS"
  tags = {
    "Environment"              = "Dev"
    "CostResponsible"          = "IT"
    "projectName"              = "crm-cost-estimate"
    "aks-managed-cluster-name" = "unknown"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg ]
}


resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "windows-python-linux-function-app" {
  name                = var.azurerm_windows_function_app
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location

  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.windows-service-plan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.windows-storage-account.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.windows-storage-account.primary_access_key
  https_only                 = true
  site_config {
    application_insights_key               = azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.instrumentation_key

    application_insights_connection_string = azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.connection_string
    application_stack {
      node_version = "~18" #FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME        
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.instrumentation_key}"
  }
  tags = {
    "Environment"              = "Dev"
    "CostResponsible"          = "IT"
    "projectName"              = "crm-cost-estimate"
    "aks-managed-cluster-name" = "unknown"
  }

}





resource "azurerm_api_management" "sharatapim" {
  name                = "sharattes-apim-func-001"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  publisher_name      = "sharat"
  publisher_email     = "sharat.bhaskar@luxairgroup.lu"
  sku_name            = "Consumption_0"


}


resource "azurerm_api_management_backend" "sharatapibackend" {
  name                = "sharattes-apim-backend-001"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  protocol            = "http"
  url                 = "https://my-function-app-url/api"

  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg,
                         azurerm_api_management.sharatapim,
                         azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app]

  credentials {
    header = {
      "x-functions-key" = "{{sharattes-apim-backend-001}}"
    }
  }

}

data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "functionkeys" {
  name                = azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name


}



resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  name                = "sharattes-import-api-001"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sharat-latestAPI"
  path                = ""
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = file("${path.module}/ExtranetAPIopenapi.yaml")

  }

 depends_on = [azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app]
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "health" {

    api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
    api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
    display_name = "health"
    method = "GET"
    operation_id = "healthy"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
    url_template = "/health"
    response {
        status_code = 200
    }
    response {
        status_code = 500
    }

}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "example" {

  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  operation_id        = "healthy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="sharattes-functionapp-001" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app
    
  ]
}
```

Error Messages:

│ Error: creating/updating Operation (Subscription: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "sharattes-rg-test-001"
│ Service Name: "sharattes-apim-func-001"
│ Api: "sharattes-import-api-001"
│ Operation: "healthy"): unexpected status 400 with error: ValidationError: One or more fields contain incorrect values:
│
│   with azurerm_api_management_api_operation.health,
│   on main.tf line 215, in resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "health":
│  215: resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "health" {
│
╵
╷

│ Error: creating or updating Operation (Subscription: "xxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "sharattes-rg-test-001"
│ Service Name: "sharattes-apim-func-001"
│ Api: "sharattes-import-api-001"
│ Operation: "healthy"): unexpected status 400 with error: ValidationError: Entity with specified identifier not found
│
│   with azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy.example,
│   on main.tf line 252, in resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "example":
│  252: resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "example" {
│
╵
PS C:\Users\sbhaskar\Desktop\testing_api>

Comment: When you are trying to execute the above code, you are facing couple of errors? Correct me if my understanding is wrong. @Sharat Bhaskar

Comment: @Jahnavi yes, earlier i was facing lot of errors but now only these two errors are there.

Comment: @SharatBhaskar, see Jahnavi's answer. The problem is likely in missing depends_on between API, operation, policy and backend.

Comment: @Jahnavi thank you so much for your help, just a thought instead of adding API management as a backend, why didn't you add the function app url? Asking this as in the end Ill have to forward the request to the backend functions which are part of the function app

Comment: Yes you can add that as well. But you need to change the XML policy content accordingly. @SharatBhaskar

Comment: @Jahnavi Just one last doubt, i want to add the system assigned managed identity access to azure function so that it cannot be publicly accessible? I found that i can do it via app registration only but when i checked on TF documentation i found a big file of azuread_application. Not sure which part should i use it for enabling system assigned managed identity on api gateway and providing access on azure function app.

Comment: Once it is deployed to the portal, you can simply add via portal itself by visiting identity blade. Is that works for you? @SharatBhaskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem when trying to update the Azure API Gateway operation backend via Terraform:

*I have made below changes to your code and was able to deploy it succcessfully.*

Identifier in policy content is not properly given. Modify your policy content as `<set-backend-service backend-id="sharattes-apim-backend-001jjj" />`. And also made few other changes accordingly to meet your requirement.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
   
  }
}
 
data "azurerm_resource_group" "windows-function-rg" {
  name     = "xxx"
}
 
 data "azurerm_storage_account" "windows-storage-account" {
  name                     = "functionsappjah"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
}
 
 
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "windows-service-plan" {
  name                = "apikurk"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
 
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "windows-application-insights" {
  name                = "application-insights-jah"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  application_type    = "Node.JS"
  depends_on = [ data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg ]
}
 
 
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "windows-python-linux-function-app" {
  name                = "kurkfuncj"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
 
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.windows-service-plan.id
  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.windows-storage-account.name
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.windows-storage-account.primary_access_key
  https_only                 = true
  site_config {
    application_insights_key      = azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.instrumentation_key
 
    application_insights_connection_string = azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.connection_string
    application_stack {
      node_version = "~18" #FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME        
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.windows-application-insights.instrumentation_key}"
  }
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management" "sharatapim" {
  name                = "sharattes-apim-func-001jjj"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  publisher_name      = "sharat"
  publisher_email     = "sharat.bhaskar@luxairgroup.lu"
  sku_name            = "Consumption_0"
 
 
}
 
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_backend" "sharatapibackend" {
  name                = "sharattes-apim-backend-001jjj"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  protocol            = "http"
  url                 = "https://my-function-app-url/api"
 
  depends_on          = [data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg,
                         azurerm_api_management.sharatapim,
                         azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app]
 
  credentials {
    header = {
      "x-functions-key" = "[sharattes-apim-backend-001]"
    }
  }
 
}
 
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "functionkeys" {
  name                = azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
 
 
}
 
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  name                = "sharattes-import-api-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sharat-latestAPI"
  path                = ""
  protocols           = ["https"]
 
depends_on = [azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app]
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "health" {
 
    api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
    api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
    display_name = "health"
    method = "GET"
    operation_id = "healthy"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
    url_template = "/health"
    response {
        status_code = 200
    }
    response {
        status_code = 500
    }
 
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "example" {
 
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.sharatapim.name
  operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.health.operation_id
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
 
  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <set-backend-service backend-id="sharattes-apim-backend-001jjj" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
 
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_function_app.windows-python-linux-function-app
   
  ]
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]